# $scope not working inside a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug, ng-show

I have the following code. I am using ng-show on html and try to manipulate it on the angular function but it did not work. I am not sure about the correct way to change a $scope value inside a function.

On Angular,

```
app.controller("ControlController", function($scope, $http, $location) {

    $scope.badRequest = false;

    $scope.login = function() {

        $http.post('/login', { 

            email: $scope.email,

            password: $scope.password

            }).then function(res) {

                $location.path('/');

            },function(err) {

                 $scope.badRequest = true;

                 console.log($scope.badRequest); // this will print true.

                 //But this  does not change the $scope.badRequest on DOM. 

            });

      };

});
```

On Jade, I have

```
.incorrect-container(ng-show='badRequest')
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you sure that variable is being set? If you put a log statement before it, is it hit?

Comment: Yes, if I put a log after function(err), it worked

Comment: After `function(err)` or inside that `function` block?

Comment: @CharlieS -- That shouldn't make a difference - `$http` is an angular module and will trigger a digest cycle. (and you don't want `$apply()` floating around in random places) - it's only listed as an answer in the provided question because `$.getJSON` doesn't trigger a digest cycle... and even then, it's still not recommended.

Comment: Is the above `ngShow` within the scope of your controller?

Comment: If the console output from the error handler is printing the right value, it probably means you are dealing w/the effects of prototypical inheritance. The $scope being used in the HTML template is inheriting from the controller's scope (b/c of an ng-if, ng-include, etc).

Comment: it does. If I set the badRequest to true something will show up but I only want to change its value to true if function(err) occurs.

Comment: I should have finished my thought: B/c your value is a boolean, the value in the parent scope is shadowed by the value in the child scope. Change the data so it's not a primitive value (string, number, boolean) to be an object that contains a boolean.

Comment: Please provide your view file to better elaborate the issue.

Comment: How does your Jade generated HTML look? And are you sure the html is inside de definition of your controller?

Comment: in .then part you have to also check server response email and password is wrong or right then you have to make $scope.badRequest = true also

Comment: @tymeJV spot on, I deleted that comment so as to not steer anyone the wrong way.

Comment: @Brother_MW, show more of your HTML code, specifically prove that it is within the scope of your controller. It should work, if there are no weird things that you haven't posted: http://plnkr.co/edit/HEvHrcYkzxva2sjR9MXO?p=preview

Comment: can we get your html output?

perhaps the ng-show is outside the scope of  controller

Comment: ng-show is outside the ng-controller so that it was not working. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's just that you copied it over wrong, but ".then" is a function call. it should be

```
$scope.login = function() {
    $http.post('/login', { 
        email: $scope.email,
        password: $scope.password
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        // do stuff in here with successfully returned data
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        $scope.badRequest = true;
    });
};
```

The way you have it, `.then` is not even being called. Also, when I ran it as it was, I got syntax errors. are you not getting those?